# Пару задач по JS+jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Товарищи, помогите, пожалуйста. С JS и jQuery не знаком, но уже сел с ними разбираться. К сожалению, на задания мне дали только неделю - прошу помочь. Вот две задачки:

1). Большинство клиентского JavaScript-а мы пишем с использованием jQuery. Для того, чтобы это было максимально оправдано, мы стараемся как можно более полно использовать возможности фреимворка, в том числе малоизвестные.

Задача. Нужно сделать плагин, позволяющий использовать, стандартным для jQuery образом, событие «клик только левой кнопкой мыши».

2). Мы уделяем большое внимание производительности наших приложений в целом. Не редко бывает, что отдельно взятая функция (например обработчик
события) работает достаточно долго, а вызывается чаще, чем было бы достаточно для пользовательских качеств всей системы.

Задача про один из способов исправить ситуацию.
Нужно реализовать общее решение (используя паттерн decorator), позволяющее вызывать любую функцию не чаще N раз в секудну, даже если вызов этой функции происходит чаще.

Спасибо.

Comment: Интересно, а это у вас на собеседовании такое спросили?

Comment: Нет, это первое задание - собеседования ещё не было...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая:

```
$(selector).click(function(){...});
```

Вторая(без декоратора):

```
var checker = true;
var time = 1000;//Задержка
function someFunction(){
    if(checker){
        //do something
        checker = false;
        window.setTimeout(function(){ checker = true;}, time);//возвели таймер
    }
}
```

Я в js и jQuery не силен, будет интересно посмотреть на реализацию с декоратором!

Comment: МЕГАреспект...спасибо огромное...)
Только правильно ля я понял, что декоратор можно "как-то стандартно" прикрутить?)

Comment: Да, можно стандартно, [вот ссылка][1], Вам нужен throttling. Сейчас сам копаюсь с этим, но что-то не хочет он нормально работать...


  [1]: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/debouncing-throttling

Comment: Ок...спасибо...)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery не просто хороша, у нее еще и [документация](http://api.jquery.com/click/) прекрасная.

С вторым вопросом, я не знаю что сказать, механизм торможения события вам нужен что ли? Я как-то плохо себе это представляю.

Comment: Да нет, это описаное ТСом возможно, просто тогда надо будет все функции "ложить" в класс который уже и будет и разруливать, задача мягко говоря нетривиальная и за спсибо лично я писать не собираюсь :)<br>а возможный алгоритм я описал

Comment: Жаль...мне-то код бы лучше посмотреть...)
Спасибо за подсказки...)

Comment: класть же

Answer (score 0):

1.

$(document).bind("click",function(event){
    if(event.which == 1) alert("mouse left!")
})